# CSS classes in Svelte components could be accidentally overwritten

Tags: css, svelte

Svelte has support for scoped CSS, means if there is a class, one more generated class will be added. For example:

```
<div class="item"></div>
```

will be transformed:

```
<div class="item item-poYXsoYvx1uy"></div>
```

and styles will be applied as `.item.item-poYXsoYvx1uy` to increase specificity. It's good.

But imagine you building a widget using Svelte and embed it to some page where the class name `item` used as well. It could easily interfere with your widget and brake styling.

I'd prefer not to have initial class names at all in the production build, just with hash ones. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target elements directly using the tag name but that will not get you very far.

In a scenario where a component is used together with unscoped styles that could cause issues, I would recommend prefixing classes.

E.g. use `.sc-item` (for "Svelte component") or something similar/more unique.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah this was my thought as well. I'm trying to use `emotion` css in js now, seems like could work out for me